# Angular ngModelChange showing duplicate value from API json data

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

UPDATE: I have reproduced the error on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dgmjyz?file=src%2Fmain.ts) for those who want to interact with the code. I have the following JSON data:

```
related_contacts: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "relationship": "Brother",
        "date_created": "2023-07-24T22:40:16.497590+03:00",
        "date_modified": "2023-07-24T22:40:16.497590+03:00",
        "case": 170,
        "created_by": 3,
        "tenant": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "relationship": "Wife",
        "date_created": "2023-07-24T22:40:16.507891+03:00",
        "date_modified": "2023-07-24T22:40:16.507891+03:00",
        "case": 170,
        "created_by": 3,
        "tenant": 2
    }
]
```

I'm trying to populate an input text field with the relationship value.

```
<div class="row py-3" *ngFor="let contact of case.related_contacts">
  <ng-container *ngIf="case.related_contacts.length > 1">
    <!--begin::Col-->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <!--begin::Label-->
      <label class="form-label text-dark fs-6">Relationship
      </label>
      <!--end::Label-->
      <!--begin::Input group-->
      <div class="form-floating mb-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ contact.relationship }}" placeholder="Relationship" [ngModel]="contact.relationship" (ngModelChange)="testChange($event)" name="{{ contact.relationship }}" formControlName="relationship" autocomplete="off"/>
        <label for="state">Relationship</label>
      </div>
      <!--end::Input group-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Col-->
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

And im using the testChange function to see the value.

```
testChange($event: any) {
  console.log($event);
},
```

There is duplication in the fields.

[image: Form Inputs]

and the console log also shows the duplicate

[image: Console Log]

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in StackBlitz? Thanks

Comment: @YongShun here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dgmjyz?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: A side note: reactive forms (`formGroup`) don't mix well with template-driven forms (`ngModel`). Stick to one recipe.

Comment: **Decide**: or use template driven Forms (input with ngModel) **or** ReactiveForms (inputs with formControlName). you **can not use** both.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating twice: through `editCaseForm.get('related_contacts')['controls']`, and inside that loop through `related_contacts` instance property, *not related in any way* to the form. For added confusion, both `ngFor`s use the same variable name:

```
<div class="collapse show" *ngFor="let contact of editCaseForm.get('related_contacts')['controls']; let i = index">
<!-- ... -->
    <div class="row py-3" *ngFor="let contact of related_contacts">
```

It isn't completely clear what exactly are you after, therefore I can't offer a complete solution.

EDIT: the outer `contact` variable is shadowed by the inner `contact`. And, using both `ngModel` and `formControl` you have two mechanisms fighting over control of the same input elements. The input is, on one hand, assigned `ngModel` from inner `contact.relationship` (so there should be two distinctive options), and on the other hand, is assigned to `formControlName="relationship"` of formGroup 0, therefore both inputs should represent the same value. Therefore, FormGroup and ngModel fight. To observe it, add

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.editCaseForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

The solution is still the same: pick either recipe, but not both.

Comment: This is an edit form. The outer loop is a field repeater. Then the inner one is for receiving API data. So, in case someone wants to add another related contact, the fields for a related contact (Relationship, Contact) are repeatable. I hope that is clearer.